# I downloaded Python 3.9 but nothing seems to have happened

Tags: python, installation, terminal

Ok, I'm trying to install python 3.9 in my computer. The only thing I know about computers is programming, and I'm starting with Python. I really don't understand much of anywhere before that, so that's why I couldn't get what I'm looking for in other StackOverflow questions and so on. I have a hard time in that. Therefore, I'll describe exactly what I did:

I went to https://www.python.org/ and downloaded Python 3.9 (that button in the middle).[image]

After it finished downloading, I opened it and went through the installation window. After it was done, I went to my Terminal (after I figured out what it was) and typed `which python`. This is where the problem starts; I got a pretty neutral return (just the path):

> /usr/bin/python

After that, I did `python`. Then there was a problem:

> WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended.
> This version is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
> Future versions of macOS will not include Python 2.7.
> Instead, it is recommended that you transition to using 'python3' from within Terminal.

> Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr 17 2020, 18:29:03)
> [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.29.20) (-macos10.15-objc- on darwin
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

All I understand is that the computer still has Python 2.7.16 installed (which, if I understand correctly, is a default for Mac), and not the 3.9. In the tutorial I was watching, this didn't happen... What can I do?

EDIT: By the way, the commands `python3.9` and `python3.9.0` gave the same error message:

```
>>> python3.9
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python3.9
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python3.9.0
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python3.9.0
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you try running 'python3' ? that should work

Comment: When you type `python` in command line, then your operating system determines which executable it executes. It checks all the folders defined in your Path environment variable, and stops on the *first* folder in the Path that contains executable file called `python`. This is the reason. You can edit your Path to put the installation folder of Python 3.9 at the top (or: left) of the list.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no experience on Mac; you have to rely on Google. At least on Windows it is pretty easy. The solution relies on the fact that your python installation folder should contain executable called `python`. On Windows, the executable on any python version is just `python.exe`.  So, before modifying your path, check that your python 3.9 installation folder contains an executable called `python`. Otherwise, use the `python3` or `python3.9` as others have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors and lines beginning with `>>>` suggest you're still inside Python2 interpreter. You need to exit it before trying to run Python3. You can do that by pressing the `Ctrl` and `d` buttons on your keyboard at the same time, or typing `exit()`.

After exiting, you should be able to run `python3`.

Answer (score 1):

looks like your python is linked to python2.7 instead of python3.

just type python3 on commandline, this should solve your problem. you can check the version by typing python3 --version on commandline.

the same should work for pip3

Comment: 'Python 3.9.0 (v3.9.0:9cf6752276, Oct  5 2020, 11:29:23) '
'[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin'
'Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.'

Did this do it?

Comment: using python3 command should work. python3.x is only needed for explicit use of a version

Answer (score -2):

The best easy way is to use anadonda based python or intel based.
[Anaconda based python for MacOS](https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.07-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg)

This should work for you.

Comment: The op is trying to install Python, which is not the same thing as Anaconda.